# gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen error for nautilus

Tags: upgrade, gnome-terminal, nautilus, ubuntu-15.04

Recently i have updated the ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04. Usually nautilus . command should open the directory in GUI.However, now i am getting the error like below.

What is the recent for that and any solution to solve it

```
vanjikumaran@vanjikumaran-ThinkPad-T530:~$ nautilus .

(nautilus:7627): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:7627): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:7627): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
vanjikumaran@vanjikumaran-ThinkPad-T530:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue as you, so I tried to run it as root

```
sudo nautilus .
```

But there were still warnings, so I found solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351950/nautilus-doesnt-work-from-command-or-from-unity).

So finally I ran

```
sudo killall nautilus
sudo apt-get purge nautilus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Or one line solution

```
sudo killall nautilus && sudo apt-get purge nautilus && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus
```